# echo category description in single.php

Tags: categories

i asked this on SO but got no where. 
i will try asking here.

this works fine in category.php `<?php echo category_description(the_category_id()); ?>`

but it does not work in single.php, just the category id shows up not the description.

any ideas, how to get this done?

thanks in advance

Edit:

in category: `<?php echo strip_tags(category_description(4)); ?>`

in single `<?php echo category_description(the_category_id()); ?>` cat id = 4

i know i'm not striping the tags..for single

i'm just trying to display the cat desc when in the single post page.

Comment: Not surprising you'd get no help for WordPress at SO; they are not WordPress enthusiasts, we are. :) Can you please provide some context for your question? Can you show the code from `category.php` where you are displaying the code where it works and where in `single.php` you want the code to work? Where you want to use it matters a bit.

Comment: @Mike thanks, actually in both cases(single + cat) I am calling the function outside the loop..right before the loop starts... i edited the q a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code that follows the screenshot:

[image: Displaying WordPress Category Description]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/Sierra_Nevada_Bigfoot_%7C_WordPress_3.0_Test_Site-20101225-232829.jpg))</sub>

```
<?php
  $categories = get_the_category();
  foreach($categories as $key => $category) {
    $url = get_term_link((int)$category->term_id,'category');
    $categories[$key] =
      "<dt><a href=\"{$url}\">{$category->name}</a></dt>" .
      "<dd>{$category->category_description}</dd>";
  }
  echo "<dl>\n" . implode("\n",$categories) . "\n</dl>";
?>
```

Also, `<?php echo category_description(the_category_id()); ?>` doesn't do what you think it does.  What follows will work on your category pages because it assumes the category ID for the category page:

```
<?php echo category_description(); ?>
```

FYI, `the_category_id()` will echo the value of the current category ID, it doesn't actually pass anything to `category_description()` is looks like was your assumption. Besides, `the_category_ID()` is [deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Deprecated_Functions_Hook) so you wouldn't want to use it anyway. By the way, I'll bet you are seeing an errant number being displayed just before the category description is displayed?

Comment: @Mike you rock. thanks a bunch. all of your answers are so straightforward. You are bettering the world. thanks man.

Comment: @andrewk - You are welcome. :)  Happy Holidays.

Comment: hey @mike take a look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529618/category-description-in-single-php-wordpress/4533957#4533957 it seems simple.I appreciate both.

Comment: @andrewk - Yes, his is simple but it does less. His only gets the first category and does not hyperlink it. Mine gets all categories assigned to a post and formats them nicely including with hyperlinks. I usually try to anticipate the things you are going to want and need and thus give more complete answers. So his is an engine. Mine is a complete car that includes an engine.   :) Hope this helped.

Comment: As always, I have learned a lot from your answer - thanks Mike.

Comment: @davemac - Thanks for saying, it's really nice to get kudos and motivates me to answer more.

Comment: How would you go about adding sorting to the output such as 'order=ASC' or 'orderby=id'

Comment: @davemac - Easiest thing would be to use one of the PHP array sort functions and sort the array in `$categories`; will that not work for you?